# Debian: Cannot install php7.4-curl -- depends not installable

Tags: php, debian, debian-buster

I recently upgraded from debian9 (stretch) to debian10 (buster).  Which also includes upgrading to php7.4.  For some reason php-curl cannot install.

I run `apt install php7.4-curl` and the error I get is:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.4-curl : Depends: libcurl3 (>= 7.44.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I cannot see any held packages, anywhere. I have tried:

```
apt-mark showhold
dpkg --audit
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get install -f
apt-get clean
apt-get update
apt-get autoremove
```

I have also tried removing curl, purge, autoremove, and then reinstall.  Same thing.

I try installing libcurl3

```
Package libcurl3 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libcurl4
```

Comment: Actually you're mistaken: Debian 10 provides php7.3 not php7.4. Hence your problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

debian10 comes with php7.3 and not php7.4

https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=php7

php 7.4 will be in next debian 11 (bullseye).

You can add some non-debian repositories:

```
wget -qO - https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php7.4 php7.4-curl
```